# Timsort Best Performance Case

Tags: python, algorithm

As we know, python uses [timsort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) for `sort` function.

Where we can find best case example for timsort, how lists should look like for best case of timsort?

Except of course case like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

**UPD** What complexity will be for case like `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: This isn't clear; you want to know the best-case input that isn't the best-case input?

Comment: I want to know alternative best input.

Comment: *"What complexity will be for case like ...?"* With a constant input, every algorithm runs in constant time. You should give a rule for the input, for example: "a growing sequence of numbers that repeats two times", or something like that

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, hmmm. I thought my example is more visible, than "growing sequence of numbers that repeats two times". But yes, that's about it.